# No output from secondary coil

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics

I have this circuit that I'm trying to repair. I cannot determine where specifically the issue begins.

The bridge rectifiers are receiving AC voltage as they were good, the problem is the the voltage output from the secondary of the transformer.

As you can see under pin 9 and 8 of T6301, it is the coil that outputs 7V of a half wave power supply. Neither 9 and 8 pins has a output voltage. It is 0 ohms.

I have no idea how the transformer was built but it was proprietary from Sony.

I wonder if that is oscillating or what part is causing oscillation for the transformer to work on DC. Maybe someone can help me.

[image: G1 Board Schematic]

Comment: Do you trust the scheme? It looks strange in some ways. The transformer is controlled by modulating current through the coil 1-3. This part is not shown. Also one would expect that D6308 anode is connected to the IC to supply low voltage to it.

Comment: I agree; the schematic looks bad.

Comment: Yeah, I mean I've repaired dozens of electronic equipments without schematics and this is the first time I've look into one due to its complicated process. It has 4 power supply sections and thats one of them. In order sfor tge whole system to boot up, Kick vcc, stanby 5v and Ac detection voltages should be in there but no. Nothings working on those pins.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the secondary coil should have an Ac out put on the pins directly from the transformer before going into the diodes and filters caps that acts as a half wave rectifier.

Comment: Is it normal by the way that a comparator has Sound hissing into it. The selection rectifier has an Lm339 comparator which should have no sound at all right?

Comment: The schematic is wrong - find a new one.

Comment: That's the only official one coming from Sony. As i check it on the actual board, it's wired up the same way.